# Для чего один ресурс использует несколько файлов куки?

Tags: http, cookie

Мне было интересно посмотреть на куки в самом браузере. Оказалось, что один сайт может использовать несколько файлов куки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: зачем несколько? В [Википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie#%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) описан механизм того, как работает передача куки файлов:

> - Сервер получает имя пользователя и пароль, проверяет их и, при их правильности, отправляет страницу успешного входа, прикрепив cookie с
>   неким идентификатором сессии.
> - Каждый раз, когда пользователь запрашивает страницу с сервера, браузер автоматически отправляет cookie с идентификатором сессии
>   серверу. Сервер проверяет идентификатор по своей базе идентификаторов
>   и, при наличии в базе такого идентификатора, «узнаёт» пользователя.

Как видно из текста, пользователю достаточно иметь один файл куки, который будет содержать идентификатор сессии. По этому одному идентификатору сервер, к которому поступает запрос, "узнает" клиента и предоставляет ему всю нужную информацию - логины, пароли и т.д.

Вопрос: Какая необходимость в нескольких файлах куки, и как следствие, нескольких идентификаторах сессии? И как браузер открывает все эти файлы? Получается, что для того, чтобы открыть все куки, которые использует ресурс, пользователь должен зайти на сайт несколько раз (несколько идентификаторов сессии - несколько сессий)?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что там "сессии"? Создатели сайта могли туда поместить все, что угодно, хоть сессию, хоть размер монитора, страну, язык, ну или корзину покупок. Также не забываем, что сессия может состоять из нескольких ключей, которые по-разному могут использоваться ресурсом. Например, при заходе вам дается один ключ, который отправляется на определенный API, тот возвращает вам другой ключ, который на стороне клиента обрабатывается, сохраняется и отправляется на другой API с логином/паролем, а в ответ вам связка еще из двух ключей. Вот уже 4 ключа в куках. Образно, но суть думаю поняли.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ _А с чего вы взяли, что там "сессии"?_ Не совсем понимаю. Неужели куки может передаваться без индентификатора сессии? Как я понял, индентификатор сессии является обязательным флагом. В [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) приведены в пример синтаксические конструкции, где везде присутствует `<cookie-name>=<cookie-value>` (этот параметр отвечает за id, насколько я понимаю): `Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value> ||
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Expires=<date> ||
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Max-Age=<non-zero-digit>...`

Comment: С куки можно работать без всяких сессий. Например можно запомнить что юзер предпочёл китайскую версию сайта русской и при следующем посещении сразу выдавать такой язык... БЕЗ АВТОРИЗАЦИИ.... ГОСТЮ

Comment: Куки можно рассматривать как общие переменные содержащие одинаковое значение в браузере, они передаются с каждым запросом браузера к серверу. Благодаря этому свойству можно сохранять любые пользовательские предпочтения, например, как отмечено выше, выбор языка на сайте. идентификатор сессии - это такая же информация, которую использует сервер для интерактивного отслеживания действий пользователя на сайте.